# Making a clickable image disappear after 10 clicks

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I need an image to "disappear" after clicking on it 10 times. What code do I use to make that happen?

Comment: It's also a great idea so give it your best shot first and then post your code with your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a counter variable to keep track of the number of clicks.

Your HTML:

```
<img src='your-img.jpg'/>
```

Your JavaScript:

```
const img = document.querySelector('img'); // Selects the image in your HTML.

let numberOfClicks = 0; // Initialize the counter

const advanceCounter = () => numberOfClicks++; // This is a function that if called, advances the counter by 1.

// Apply a 'click' event listener
img.onclick = function(ev) {
   if (numberOfClicks >= 10)
      this.style.display = 'none'
   else advanceCounter()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can done this with single line of code

```
<img src="/test.png" onclick="window.counter=(window.counter??0)+1;window.counter>=10?this.remove():null">
```

**window.counter** is global variable which increment and if its reach 10 click its will remove its own element